# Builder Pattern with Inheritance in JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance, builder

Suppose i have a class which extends from another class:

```
class Parent{
    private String p1;
    public void setP1(String p1){
        this.p1 = p1;
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    private int c1;
    public void setC1(int c1){
        this.c1 = c1;
    }
}
```

I use the Builder Pattern to create an instance of the class Parent:

```
class ParentBuilder{
    aParent(){ return new ParentBuilder()}


    with(String p1){
        this.p1 = p1;
    }

    public Parent build(){
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setP1(this.p1);
        return parent;
    }
}
```

How can i use the builder pattern for the class Child to do things like

```
aParent().with("test").build();
aChild().with(4).build();
aChild().with(4).with("test").build();
aChild().with("test").with(4).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement an abstract builder class, the way I'd do this is first create a an `Abstract Person` class that `Parent` and `Child` class will inherit from:

```
public abstract class Person {

    private String p1;

    private Person(AbstractBasicBuilder builder) {
        this.p1 = builder.p1;
    }

    public void setP1(String p1) {
        this.p1 = p1;
    }

    public String getP1() {
        return p1;
    }

    public abstract static class AbstractBasicBuilder<T extends AbstractBasicBuilder> {

       private String p1;        

        AbstractBasicBuilder withP1(String p1) {
            this.p1 = p1;
            return this;
        }

        abstract Person build();        

    }
}
```

Once you have this I would then create my `Parent` and `Child` classes, not sure the inheritance is right in your code to have `Child` inherit from `Parent`.

```
public class Parent extends Person {

    private Parent(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
    }

    public abstract static class Builder extends AbstractBasicBuilder<Person.Builder> {

        @Override
        public Parent build() {
            return new Parent(this);
        }
}
```

Now that we have our `Parent` class we can implement our `Child` class where we will add to the build class so we can provide a mother and father as well.

```
public class Child extends Person {

    private Parent father;

    private Parent mother;

    private Child(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.father = builder.father;
        this.mother = builder.mother;
    }

    public Parent getFather() {
        return father;
    }

    public Parent getMother() {
        return mother;
    }

    public abstract static class Builder extends AbstractBasicBuilder<Child.Builder> {

        private Parent father;

        private Parent mother;         

        Builder withFather(Parent father) {
            this.father = father;
            return this;
        }

        Builder withMother(Parent mother) {
            this.mother = mother;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Child build() {
            return new Child(this);
        }
    }

}
```

So what we have done here is we have create 3 classes altogether, we have our `Person` abstract class that implements p1 for us so we don't need to duplicate code in multiple classes. We then have our abstract builder class that implements the basic code for building a `Person` object.

We have then implemented `Parent` class that extends `Person` class and then implements the `AbstractBasicBuilder` which constructs our `Parent` object.

We then implemented `Child` class that also extends `Person` - not `Parent`, a `Child` may become a `Parent` in the future but they are not always a `Parent` - in this class we have 2 i

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hierarchy of classes the builders are required for, the builders should be implemented properly with their own hierarchy.

The proper builder implementation won't allow setting fields that don't belong to the built object. E.g. if `Parent` doesn't have `c1` field, it shouldn't be allowed to set it via `parentBuilder().withC1(val).build();`

For example, if you have the following objects hierarchy:

```
        GrandPa
           |
        Parent
           |
          / \
    Child1   Child2
```

It would be reasonable to create the builder's hierarchy as in the code below:

GrandPa class with builders:

```
public class GrandPa {
    private Integer gp;

    public void setGp(Integer gp) {
        this.gp = gp;
    }

    public static class GrandPaBuilder extends 
                GrandPaBuilderWithResult<GrandPaBuilder, GrandPa> {

        public static GrandPaBuilder grandPaBuilder() {
            return new GrandPaBuilder();
        }

        @Override
        public GrandPa build() {
            GrandPa grandPa = new GrandPa();
            grandPa.setGp(gp);

            return grandPa;
        }
    }

    public static abstract class GrandPaBuilderWithResult<T extends 
                GrandPaBuilderWithResult<T, R>, R extends GrandPa> {

        Integer gp;
        public T withGP(Integer gp) {
            this.gp = gp;
            return (T) this;
        }

        public abstract R build();
    }
}
```

Parent class with builders:

```
public class Parent extends GrandPa {
    private String p;

    public void setP(String p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public static class ParentBuilder extends 
                ParentBuilderWithResult<ParentBuilder, Parent> {

        public static ParentBuilder parentBuilder() {
            return new ParentBuilder();
        }

        @Override
        public Parent build() {
            Parent parent = new Parent();
            parent.setGp(gp);
            parent.setP(this.p);

            return parent;
        }
    }

    public static abstract class ParentBuilderWithResult<T extends 
                ParentBuilderWithResult<T, R>, R extends Parent> extends 
                GrandPaBuilderWithResult<T, R> {

        protected String p;

        public T withP(String p) {
            this.p = p;
            return (T) this;
        }
    }
}
```

And child classes with builders:

```
public class Child1 extends Parent {

    private Double c1;

    public void setC1(Double c1) {
        this.c1 = c1;
    }

    public static class Child1Builder extends 
                ParentBuilderWithResult<Child1Builder, Child1> {

        private Double c1;

        public static Child1Builder child1Builder() {
            return new Child1Builder();
        }

        public Child1Builder withC1(Double c1) {
            this.c1 = c1;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Child1 build() {
            Child1 child1 = new Child1();
            child1.setGp(gp);
            child1.setP(p);
            child1.setC1(this.c1);

            return child1;
        }
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {

    private Double c2;

    public void setC2(Double c2) {
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    public static class Child2Builder extends 
                ParentBuilderWithResult<Child2Builder, Child2> {

        private Double c2;

        public static Child2Builder child2Builder() {
            return new Child2Builder();
        }

        public Child2Builder withC2(Double c2) {
            this.c2 = c2;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Child2 build() {
            Child2 child2 = new Child2();
            child2.setGp(gp);
            child2.setP(p);
            child2.setC2(this.c2);

            return child2;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the usage of self-bound generics in the builders to always return only desired object reference.
This implementation is safe and won't allow putting errors in your code via the builders.

You can use them in the following way:

```
GrandPa grandPa = GrandPa.GrandPaBuilder.grandPaBuilder().withGP(1).build();
Parent parent = Parent.ParentBuilder.parentBuilder().withGP(2).withP("p").build();
Child1 child1 = Child1.Child1Builder.child1Builder().withGP(3).withP("p1").withC1(1D).build();
Child2 child2 = Child2.Child2Builder.child2Builder().withGP(3).withP("p2").withC2(2D).build();
```

Comment: You are right setting a field of the child with the parent builder doesn‘t make sense and i don’t want to have this property.